# A good belgian wit recipe for Indian climate?

Tags: beer, belgian

Cheers! I know there are a few good ones out there but I'm not sure if temperature is going to play a weighted part here. I'm from India and the temperature at the place i live in ranges between 25C and 32C. What would be the right recipe in terms of grain bill (for OG 1.050), hops and especially the yeast?

Comment: Welcome to homebrewing! Is it possible for you to list the availability of particular brands of brewing yeasts available to you? For instance- do you have access to Safale or Whitelabs brands? Apologies, I'm really unfamiliar with the brewing market in India! Temperature is a large factor in yeast choice- but I want to make sure I provide suggestions that you can actually use!

Comment: Safale is available. Whitelabs is rare.